# Would a guide to MathJax be useful here?

Tags: discussion

Over on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange there is [How do I add mathematical notation using Latex MathJax?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/607/how-do-i-add-mathematical-notation-using-latex-mathjax)

This gives some useful pointers on the kinds of things that are commonly required when writing questions and answers there, and links to a much more comprehensive guide on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Could we benefit from a similar guide on our meta site, focusing on things most relevant to computer graphics (matrix notation, Greek letters)?

Comment: I'm wondering this after seeing a question here on Computer Graphics that had a matrix equation too long to fit the width of the question, so the right hand side was cut off. I fixed this just by making the equation `\small` but I had to look up how to do this on the Worldbuilding post, so I wondered if we could use one here that people can easily find/link to.